# 18.04 How to make MySQL Workbench look better in GNOME?

Tags: mysql-workbench

How can I make MySQL Workbench look better in the GNOME interface of Ubuntu 18.04?

The main problem are the tab heights, they are too large and occupy most part of the screen. MySQL Workbench for Linux seems to have very limited view customization compared to the windows version.

[image]

Comment: @K7AAY VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"